# The infimum $\inf_{(a,b) \in A\times B} \; \rho(a,b)$ is attained for any two compact sets $A,B$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be compact sets in $(S,\rho)$. Define $\rho(A,B)$ by $$\rho(A,B) = \inf_{(a,b) \in A\times B} \; \rho(a,b)$$ Show that there exists $a_0 \in A, b_0 \in B$ s.t. $$\rho(A,B) = \rho(a_0,b_0)$$

I don't think I understand the question correctly. It is asking me to show that there are a pair of points, $a_0,b_0$, s.t. the metric $\rho(A,B)$ exists?

$\rho(A,B)$ is defined to be $\rho(A,B) = \inf_{(a,b) \in A\times B} \; \rho(a,b)$ and since metrics have to be positive they are bounded below, i.e., $\rho(A,B) \geq 0$, it must have an infimum. Hence, $\rho(A,B)$ must exist.

Is this what the question wanted?

Comment: As a matter of fact, $\rho$ is not a metric. But this is not important. You are asked to prove that the infimum is *attained* by some pair $(a_0,b_0)$.  To be *attained* is not the same as to *exist*. The infimum of $1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$ is not attained, but it exists, and is equal to $0$. You may want to recall that a continuous function on a compact set attains its extreme values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the metric $D$ on $A \times B$ defined by $D((x,y), (a,b)) = \rho(x,a) + \rho(y,b)$, for all $(x,y), (a,b)\in A\times B$. The mapping $f : (A \times B, D) \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(a,b) = \rho(a,b)$ is continuous, since $$|f(x,y) - f(a,b)| \le D((x,a), (y,b))$$ for all $(x,y), (a,b)\in A\times B$. Indeed, by the triangle inequality, $$f(x,y) - f(a,b) \le \rho(x,a) + \rho(a,y) - \rho(a,b) \le \rho(x,a) + \rho(y,b) = D((x,y),(a,b))$$ and similarly $f(a,b) - f(x,y) \le D((x,y),(a,b))$.

Now since $A$ and $B$ is compact, so is $A\times B$. Hence $f$, being a continuous mapping from a compact space, has a minimum, i.e., there exists $(a_0, b_0)\in A\times B$ such that $f(a_0,b_0) = \inf\{f(a,b):(a,b)\in A\times B\}$. That is, $$\rho(a_0,b_0) = \rho(A,B).$$

Comment: I don't understand the motivation behind the very first part? For instance, why do you create a new metric $D$? Also, $d$ is not defined.

Comment: @Lrkety I mistakenly placed $d$ for $\rho$. To point of introducing $D$ was to define a continuous map $f$ between $A\times B$ and $\Bbb R$, as metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

define $\phi:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $\phi(a)=d(a,B)$ where $d(a,B)=inf\{d(a,b):b\in B\}$

check that $\phi$ is continuous and $A$ is compact and hence $\phi$ attains its bounds So $\exists a\in A$ such that $\phi(a)=inf\{d(a,B):a\in A\}=d(A,B)$